# Unable to display initialized char array, gives segfault

Tags: c++

I am busy writing a function to draw a 2D character map from a given text file. When I use **std::cout** directly after the initialized variable **map[i][j]** it works fine, but when I try the same thing elsewhere (even in the same function) I get a segfault. (See code below)

The initialized variable is global so it is not a scope problem, yet I cannot wrap my head around why it doesn't work.

Before everyone shouts "duplicate", I have looked through all the related questions but none of them provide a valid solution.

In my .h file I have the following:

```cpp
#ifndef LEVEL_H   //Gets Overwritten by an automarker so I cannot change anything in this file
#define LEVEL_H

#include "Exceptions.h"

class Level
{
 private:
  char ** map; 
  int map_rows, map_columns;
  int entity_count;

 public:
  Level();
  ~Level();

  void loadFile(std::string filename); 
  void draw();
  void mainLoop();  

};

#endif
```

In my .cpp implementation file I have:

```cpp
#include "Level.h"
#include "Exceptions.h"

#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <exception>

Level::Level()
{
    map_rows = 0;
    map_columns = 0;
    entity_count = 0;
}

void Level::loadFile(std::string filename)
{

    std::cout << "Loading level file "
              << filename << std::endl;

    bool mapSet = false;

    try
    {
        std::ifstream inFile;
        inFile.open(filename.c_str());
        std::string line;
        getline(inFile, line);
        char *cstr = &line[0];
        map_rows = cstr[0] - 48;             //Initialize rows map_size. The files are in fixed format, the first char is the number of rows (I have - 48 here because ASCII)
        std::cout << map_rows << std::endl;  //Output here: 5
        if (!inFile)
        {
            FileException FE;             //Custom exception classes from Exceptions.h to be thrown if file read error. Just replace with "throw 1" and "catch(int)" for reproduction
            throw FE;
        }

        try
        {
            for (int a = 1; a < line.size(); a++)
            {
                if (cstr[a] == NULL)
                {
                    NullPointerException e("Set Entities");
                    throw e;
                }
                //The files will always be in the same format, with the first line containing 3 digits which are seperated by whitespaces
                if (cstr[a] != ' ')       //idiot checks not so important here because I know the files are all 'clean'. 
                {
                    map_columns = cstr[a] - 48;   //initialize the no. of columns with first non-whitespace after cstr[0] (which was the rows)
                    cstr[a] = ' ';   //set digit to whitespace so that the next initialization passes over it.
                }
            }

            for (int b = 1; b < line.size(); b++)
            {
                if (cstr[b] == NULL)
                {
                    NullPointerException e("Set Entities");
                    throw e;
                }

                if (cstr[b] != ' ')
                {
                    entity_count = cstr[b] - 48;  //the number of entities set to the last remaining non-whitespace digit
                    cstr[b] = ' ';
                }
            }
        }
        catch (NullPointerException &e)
        {
            std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
        }

        while (getline(inFile, line))
        {
            if (mapSet != false)
            {
                map = new char *[map_rows];
                for (int i = 0; i < map_rows; i++)
                {
                    map[i] = new char[map_columns];
                    for (int j = 0; j < map_columns; j++)
                    {
                        map[i][j] = line[j];
                        std::cout << map[i][j];
                    }
                    getline(inFile, line);
                    std::cout << "\n";
                }
                mapSet = true;
                std::cout << map << std::endl; //Doesn't output anything
                std::cout << map[0][0] << std::endl;  //Also does not ouput anything here
            }

            std::string entType;                    //this part just lists the entities present in the text file
            entType = line.substr(0, line.size());
            std::cout << entType << std::endl;
        }

        std::cout << map[0][0] << std::endl; //segfault here

    }
    catch (FileException &FE)
    {
        std::cerr << FE.what() << '\n';
    }
}
```

...it is called from my main in the following manner:

```cpp
#include "Level.h"

int main()
{
    level level;
    level.loadFile("level2.txt");  //<--all the cout statements here are for testing and will be removed later
    level.draw();
    level.mainLoop();

return 0;
}
```

This is the content of the textfile which is being loaded:

```
5 5 3    //First line always in fixed order
#####
#a c#
#   #
#d b#
#####
a start
b exit
c teleporter tele1 a
d button tele1
```

My output and the error message looks as follows: (and yes I have to use c++98)

```
./maze
Maze game
5 5 3
#####
#a c#
#   #
#d b#
#####
a start
b exit
c teleporter tele1 a
d button tele1
makefile:23: recipe for target 'run' failed
make: *** [run] Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Ok so after a little digging I found out that by removing `map = NULL;` in the constructor `Level::level` that it compiles fine, but I get the following garbage output:

```cpp
Maze game
Loading level file level2.txt
5
Null pointer encountered: variable 
#####
#a c#
#   #
#d b#
#####
a start
b exit
c teleporter tele1 a
d button tele1
�
In draw function 
�F
H��
�O{
-+x
-+x
After draw function 
In draw function 
�F
H��
�O{
-+x
-+x
After draw function 
Type your next move (w:up, s:down, a:left, d:right), L to load another level, or Q to quit: 
^Cmakefile:23: recipe for target 'run' failed
make: *** [run] Interrupt
```

Comment: Even in C++98, we got `std::vector` and `std::string`.

Comment: Just to be sure, 'a' 'b' 'c' and 'd' are the obstacles?

Comment: Please attach a debugger and provide a stack trace.

Comment: What does your makefile look like?

Comment: `//...assume read from file process is correct...  //...assume rowSize and colSize have been set...` -- And then we get to waste time if these assumptions are false.  If you're going to comment like this, then how about hardcoding a 3x3 or 4x4 data into the program itself.

Comment: `if(mapIsSet != false)` looks very suspicious - the code you show never enters the `if` body. In fact I'm quite sure that's the issue - it explains the segfault.

Comment: This code is too fragmented and incomplete to compile.  Help us help you.  [mcve]

Comment: `level level();` -- Is this right?  This doesn't create an object.  Get rid of the parentheses, and change the name of the variable to something other than `level`.

Comment: `getline(inFile,line)  //<---get input for next row` is also missing a semicolon... And there's a missing closing brace in `loadFile`. These are all errors that everyone who wants to try out your code would have to fix first. If you post compileable code, it is a lot easier for people to help you.

Comment: If you're reading into line where line is presumably the same size as `colSize` you should be using `line[j]` not `line[i]`. In general, if this is a game, probably not the best way to load data.

Comment: @Damian-TeodorBeleș yes, those are the obstacles but a is used to represent self so there is always 1 less number of entities than shown.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie sorry about that, it was `level level` in my original code I was just lost in thought when typing `level()`

Comment: Provide the whole code please. Don't assume anything.

Comment: @Damian-TeodorBeleș Will do so now, but keep in mind it is quite long and most of it is unrelated to the question at hand

Comment: Copy/paste is your friend. There's no excuse for having `level level()` instead of `Level level`.

Comment: @Oom_Ben Not the whole code; just enough to reproduce the problem and be complete, as in [mcve].

Comment: @Oom_Ben `for (int a = 1; a < sizeof(line); a++)` -- This is incorrect.  The `line` is a `std::string`, and to get the number of characters, it is `line.size()`.  The `sizeof` gives you the number of bytes the `std::string` class takes up -- it does **not** give you the number of characters.  With that line of code, you are either going to read too many, too few, and in a hugely lucky situation, the right number of characters.  This is also why you should never assume things "work" -- this is evidence right here, where you didn't initially show this faulty code.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie gosh thanks, I replaced all instances of `sizeof(line)` with `line.size()` but I still get the same output.

Comment: using `map[i][j] = line.at(j);` was also tried, but it does not make any difference to the execution of the function